# React-Node.js app can't connect to SQL Server database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs

This is my first time attempting this type of tech stack and I am not sure what I am missing to get my database to connect. When I attempt to go to `/api/broker`, it just loads for a long time... also, I never get the message that server is working from my / route.

When I stop the loading of the `/api/broker` route, I get this message:

> Proxy Error: See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

How would I get the SQL Server to accept the connection? Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?

This is my app.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
// import './server';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
      data: null
    };
  
    componentDidMount() {
        // Call our fetch function below once the component mounts
      this.callBackendAPI()
        .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
      // Fetches our GET route from the Express server. (Note the route we are fetching matches the GET route from server.js
    callBackendAPI = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/api/broker');
      const body = await response.json();
  
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw Error(body.message) 
      }
      return body;
    };

    render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
      
      </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

And this is my server.js file:

```html
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function(res, req, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

var dbConfig = {
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    server: "jdbc:sqlserver://sql3\\misc",
    database: "ReactApp_DB"
};

//Function to connect to database and execute query
var  executeQuery = function(res, query){             
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {   
                    console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
                    res.send(err);
                 }
                 else {
                        // create Request object
                        var request = new sql.Request();
                        // query to the database
                        request.query(query, function (err, res) {
                          if (err) {
                                     console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                                     res.send(err);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      res.send(res);
                                      console.log("Querying database ");
                                           }
                              });
                      }
     });           
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.send('Server is working...');
});

//GET API
app.get("/api/broker", function(req , res){
    console.log('brokers queried: ');
    var query = "select * from [broker]";
    executeQuery (res, query);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function (){
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("app now running on port ", port);
});
```

Comment: Do you need to specify the port on your db config and did you you setup the proxy?

Comment: as @iqbal125 stated, you may need to specify the port, and also verify if you're able to connect via SQL Auth. MS SQL Server by default only let you connect via NTLM.

Comment: @Omar I have not been able to connect to Ms Sql. So my question is what am I missing to connect?  I also am not sure what NTLM is?

Comment: Check in the MS SQL configuration if it's enabled SQL Authentication. Otherwise you would need to use NTLM, which is an Authentication protocol that uses Windows Bundled Authentication.

Comment: @Omar, it is set up with SQL Server & Windows Auth mode. I think the issue is with the code. When I run node server.js nothing happens...

Comment: @Stacie nothing will happen when you run the server, as you set it up to connect in every request

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix

in your package.json in your React app, enter:

"proxy": base URI where node app is running.

for example

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Proxy is what allows your react app to make requests as if it were the node server. Because '/api/broker' is a route on your node server not in your react app. So a proxy allows your react app to make a request as if it were your node server. with the URI path of:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/broker
```

even though your react app is running on localhost:3000. Without the proxy I assume your are currently just accessing the route.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/broker
```

which doesnt do anything since it is not a valid route.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the proxies. The problem is connecting from node to the database.

Comment: You got Proxy Error in the console did you not?

Comment: How is your react app connected to your server, is this a development or built project

Comment: @iqbal125 I actually had proxy listed in my package.json, that's when it throws that proxy error. If I remove that line, I don't get the error but that doesn't solve my issue of trying to connect to the database. So do I need to keep this line of code in there?  Currently this is running in development.

Comment: If this is a development build then yes, there is no other way to do it, you have to run both your react app and node server separately. Then make api calls through a proxy.

Comment: Also remove the headers and use the CORS library in your express server.

Comment: Your issue is mostly likely CORS related